# Jar file will not run. Get's an error in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation, cmd

I can not get my jar file to run so I did  "java -Xmx1024m -jar test.jar" in cmd and I get a lot of errors.

I have image resources and a jar library set up in paths. It works fine in eclipse though. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ImagePanel.<init>(FinalRevNoise.java:117)
        at FinalRevNoise.createAndShowGUI(FinalRevNoise.java:53)
        at FinalRevNoise.access$0(FinalRevNoise.java:48)
        at FinalRevNoise$1.run(FinalRevNoise.java:42)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is where I define the spries and sheets

```
BufferedImage bigImg; //sprite sheets
BufferedImage bigImg2;
BufferedImage bigImg3;

BufferedImage[] sprites; //individual sprites
BufferedImage[] sprites2;
BufferedImage[] sprites3;
```

code around 117

```
public ImagePanel(){
         try {

             bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("res/sheet.png")); //sprite sheet paths
             bigImg2 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/sheet2.png"));
             bigImg3 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/sheet3.png"));


         } catch (IOException e) {
         }

         final int width = 20; //sprite width/height = 20 pixels
         final int height = 20;
         final int rows = 6; // 6 rows and 5 collums
         final int cols = 5;
         sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * cols]; //sets up the sprite arrays
         sprites2 = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];
         sprites3 = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];

         for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //goes through sprite sheet and puts sprites into an array
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
             {
                 sprites[(i * cols) + j] = bigImg.getSubimage( //this is line 117
                     j * width,
                     i * height,
                     width,
                     height
                 );
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: Instead of screendumping, can you paste the error so we can copy-paste it ourselves and help you? Some code would be helpful as well--FinalRevNoise.java around line 117 especially.

Comment: @hexafraction added code around line 117. Not sure how to copy in cmd though.

Comment: @SolidCloudinc Right click, select mark, select your text, then press enter.

Comment: Well, you've got a null pointer at line 117.  Assuming the listing is accurate, could be "sprites", could be "bigImg".

Comment: @HotLicks I don't see why though. It works fine in the IDE but doesn't with a .jar? Am I missing something

Comment: Probably what the guy said below about the file not being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 117:

```
sprites[(i * cols) + j] = bigImg.getSubimage(
```

Since you get a NullPointerException here, either sprites is null, or bigImg is null.
sprites cannot be null since you just set it to a new array. Therefore bigImg is null.

Why is bigImg null? Because

```
ImageIO.read(new File("res/sheet.png"))
```

threw an IOException.

Comment: Okay why does that not throw an exception on the IDE but does with a .jar? Am I not pointing my files correctly or is there an extra step I needed to do that I have missed?

Comment: Is there a res folder containing the image in the current directory when the jar file is executed?  If you can, it is better to put images in the jar file and use one of the getResource methods to access it.

Comment: @NormR +1 I did that and it worked great. I also had to add the folder the spritesheet was in to my properties then file path. Thanks.

Comment: Also, this is why catching exceptions and doing nothing is a bad idea. If you'd at least printed the exception, you'd know it was being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us where is the jar file is in relationship to the ***`res`*** folder?

The NullPointerException at line 117 goes back to line

```
bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("res/sheet.png"));
```

It's very likely that your jar file is not in the same project folder which contains ***`src`***, and ***`res`*** folders.  If you put your jar file there, `bigImg` will not be null.